# start a remote service and receive a result in Android

Tags: android, service, android-intent, intentfilter

I have two applications.
One app has the Activity and another one is a background service.

I can able to access the service app from my activity app using implicit intent filters.

I need to receive a result from the service.

For ex:

From activity app, i am going to start the service and send a data.
In the service app, i need to receive the data and do some inspections and need to return to the activity app as modified result.

I can able to send by *putExtra* and can able to retrieve it in the service by *getExtra*. I need to return a value from service and receive it in activity app.

PS: The thing i needed is, the same way what we do with *finish()* and *onActivityResult()* with the Activity results.

Thanks in advance to you masters...

Comment: Did you tried using a ContentProvider?

Comment: @DGomez Thanks to you. I tried with content provider. But i need to send a simple text and receive. so i am looking for an elegant solution to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to communicate through intent while there is a perfectly working binder protocol.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

If an activity starts a service with 'bindService()' then the service will run until the activity calls 'unbindService()'.

Answer (score 2):

First add a class like this:

```
package com.test.context; //For example
public class MyContext extends Application
{
   //Here you define the attributes to share through the application
   // with setters and getters
}
```

and in the AndroidManifest.xml, add the path of the class,
in the example is com.test.context so:

```
<application android:name="com.test.context.MyContext"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your code you can do some like this:

```
MyContext ctx = (MyContext)getApplication();
```

And you will be able to share data in all the app, btw activities and services, i did it this way in a Tasker , and works fine.

Comment: He says he has 2 applications, then you cannot do this.

Comment: Thanks dude. I have two apps. so is it good to communicate like this. After some research i feel for plugin processes like this. We have some solutions. There are in stackoverflow also. Anyway i will come up with the detailed solution here soon.

Comment: Dude For Plugin Services I just followed  [this article](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/06/plugins.html) . I hope everybody will find it as useful.