# if( current screen == R.layout.main )

Tags: android, xml, view

I have 3 layouts; main.xml , secondscreen.xml , thidrscreen.xml.

I want to overwrite on Back button like currentscreen (which screen is open).

```
if( currentscreen == R.layout.main)
{
  do something
}
   else ( currentscreen == R.layout.secondscreen )
   {
     do something
   }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not 3 different Activities for each layout?? , whay are you trying to do??

Comment: +1 to different activities. It becomes a pain managing variables and all of the code when you try to do everything in one activity

Comment: I am afraid of using Intent between activities. Because I have too many things which are sharing between my methods(which are for layouts)..

Comment: You can use a Context to share data, is veery very simple, here the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142372/1174201

Comment: Thanks, It seems very useful for my application. But I have a question if I extend my class to the "Application" how can I handle the back button issue with "Activity". I mean you said I have to extend my class to "Activity" for use transition between layouts on back button. But if I extend it to the "Application" how can I extend to the "Activity" ?

Comment: There are two different things, the Application class is to share data btw Activities, so, you create a Context which extends Application, this class is ONLY to share data btw Activities isn't an Activity itself, then you  create 3 classes which extends Activity and for each one you use the respective layout, and in each Activity you can get the context you created and put or get data, this data will be available for all the Activities in the app

Comment: I got it and I will try it right now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you'd want to do this, exactly, but if you have an ID on the top level view within your layout, you could probably do:

```
 if ( getContentView().getId() == R.id.myTopLevelViewFromMain ){
      // do stuff
 } else if ( getContentView().getId() == R.id.myTopLevelViewFromSecondScreen ){
      // do other stuff
 }
```

etc.

Alternately, as suggested on the comments to your question (and this is probably the better design choice), you can use multiple activities.

Yet a third way would be to use 3 top-level views within your layout, and manipulate their visibility as necessary.